# Why 301-redirect doesn't work?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need make redirect from site/article to site/article/

I use this rule in .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^/article(.*)$ http://balttranscom.ru/article/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but it's not work!

Help!

Answer (score 4):

As shown at the bottom of the [mod_rewrite documentation page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html), rules in `.htaccess` files aren't passed an initial slash.

```
RewriteRule ^article(.*)$ http://balttranscom.ru/article/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the following line?

```
RewriteEngine On
```